# Add "export as pdf" in my page with javascript and css file

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to add to my site for each article an "export as pdf" button, which the style I want to get from my print stylesheet file.

Which javascript library (or any other solution) I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I use in my applications mPDF. Its very easy to use. And they have also a lot of example scripts to show step by step it's possibilities.

[mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

It works with PHP, because there is a lot of file manipulation necessary.

Comment: I think that ready tool that only take html page and css stylesheet and generate pdf can be found.